# Unity's Input System not registering Dualshock 4 input

Tags: unity, bluetooth

I have a Dualshock 4 controller that I use on PC (mostly for Steam games on Windows 10). Its inputs register just fine under `Game Controllers/Properties`, but Unity has thus far been unable to see any DS4 input at all.

The USB connector on the top side of this particular DS4 controller is dead, so I charge via the bottom connector and play my PC games using bluetooth exclusively.

Is there something I have to configure in order to get Unity to see my DS4 controller? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Hmmm... I've successfully controlled Unity games with a DS4 via Bluetooth in the past, using DS4Windows if I recall correctly.

Comment: @DMGregory I believe programs like DS4Windows basically mimic XBox controllers. Might give it a try, just odd that Unity doesn't support DS4 bluetooth out of the box. Or it does and I just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I did use it without DS4Win, but it put the axes in a confusing order. Are you using the old Input Manager or the new Input System Package? If you're not using the new system, it might be worth trying it out to see if it handles your case better out of the box.

Comment: Based on the [gamepad](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Gamepad.html#playstation-controllers) & [HID](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HID.html) docs, it looks like it's supported. Can you find the HID descriptor from the Input Debugger as described in the HID docs link?